# Ionic accordion list

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, accordion

I have an accordion list in my Ionic app which looks like following:

[image]

At the place of black square I want to have a green(or any color) LED types looking button/symbol which will be shown if that particular exercise is already watched, basically something like an indicator.

The code for this accordion list is as follows:

```
<ion-view view-title="Trainingsplan">
<ion-content class="has-header">

<div ng-if="authenticated == true">

<ion-list>
  <div ng-repeat="day in days"><br>
    <div class="item item-icon-left"  ng-click="toggleGroup(day)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(day)}">
      <i class="icon icon-accessory" ng-class="isGroupShown(day) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
      &nbsp;
      {{day.name}}
    </div>
    <a class="item item-icon-left item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(day)" ng-repeat="exercise in day.exercises" type="item-text-wrap"
       href="#/tab/plan/{{exercise.id}}">
      {{exercise.name}}
    </a>
  </div>
</ion-list>
</div>

 <div ng-if="authenticated!=true">Fail</div>

 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I did it like following:

```
<ion-list>
  <div ng-repeat="day in days"><br>
    <div class="item item-icon-left"  ng-click="toggleGroup(day)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(day)}">
      <i class="icon icon-accessory" ng-class="isGroupShown(day) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
      &nbsp;
      {{day.name}}
    </div>
    <a class="item item-icon-left item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(day)" ng-repeat="exercise in day.exercises" type="item-text-wrap"
       href="#/tab/plan/{{exercise.id}}">
      {{exercise.name}}

      <!-- Trial LED -->

        <span style="float:right;"><i ng-show="isWatched" class="ion-checkmark-round"></i></span>

    </a>
  </div>
</ion-list>
```